# Erro ao instalar Slim framework

Tags: php, composer, slim, slimframework

Como corrigir o erro abaixo, utilizando o composer.

Código do **composer.json** já criado na pasta bin\ :

```
{
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "2.*"
    }
}
```

[image: Erro]

Comment: De acordo com essa [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25986258/1452488), talvez você precise excluir a variável de ambiente referente ao Composer.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss não resolveu...o composer continua exibindo essa mensagem!

Comment: Composer could not find the config file: C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section

Comment: Dentro de que pasta `bin` você criou esse arquivo?

Comment: Correto bin/composer.json -> {
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "2.*"
    }
}

Comment: Eu executei o comando a partir do `composer` global e funcionou perfeitamente. Nem precisou de algum arquivo `composer.json`, já que está utilizando o `create-project`. Tenta rodar o comando com o `composer` instalado globalmente ou coloque o arquivo `composer.json` na raiz de onde criará o projeto.

Comment: php composer.phar instal este comando ???

Comment: Mas você está fazendo `install` ou `create-project`?

Comment: php composer.phar install dentro do app1/  contendo o composer.json

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59949/discussion-between-anderson-carlos-woss-and-alexjosesilva).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como discutido nesta [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25986258/composer-could-not-find-the-config-file) no SOen e nesta [issue](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1720) no repositório oficial do Composer, o erro é gerado devido a uma incompatibilidade gerada no Windows quando a variável de ambiente `COMPOSER` é definida. A solução prática é acessar as variáveis de ambiente e removê-la, não esquecendo de reiniciar o computador após o processo. Feito isso, o comando deve funcionar normalmente.

Answer (score 1):

**Installation**

Crie uma pasta no seu xampp com qualquer nome e depois navegue pelo cmd até ela:

```
cd c:\xampp\htdocs\NomeDaPasta
```

**Instalação com Composer**

Instale o composer em seu projeto

```
php -r "eval('?>'.file_get_contents('https://getcomposer.org/installer'));"
```

depois no cmd ainda:

```
echo @php "%~dp0composer.phar" %*>composer.bat
```

crie o composer.json na pasta:

```
{
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "2.*"
    }
}
```

apos isso use o comando:

```
php composer.phar install
```

Crie o index.php:

```
<?php
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Comment: O mesmo erro:  Composer could not find the config file: C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section

Comment: Aqui foi normal: http://imgur.com/a/aFqgQ

Comment: meu composer.json na pasta bin/ {
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "2.*"
    }
}

Comment: a proxy atrapalha ???

Comment: Tem vez que sim

Comment: se meu json ...não esta errado..so pode ser o proxy ou firewall

Comment: Os comandos você usou igual aos que passei?

Comment: Correto. Tudo igual!!!

Comment: Qual a versão do seu composer?

Comment: Composer version 1.4.2 2017-05-17 08:17:52

Comment: Da um composer update e ve se cria o arquivo composer.lock

Comment: composer update
Composer could not find the config file: C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section

Comment: O Composer could not find the config file: C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin que você possui uma variável de ambiente COMPOSER definida e configurada para C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin. Você deve desmarcar / excluir esse env var.

Comment: conseguir corrigir...obrigado